# R: Error in sample.int(): NMOF Package

Tags: r, function, random, heuristics, portfolio

I am trying to replicate the following code (based on Financial Optimization in R by @EnricoSchumann) but I got the following error. The code tries to solve Markowitz Model with cardinality constraint. Further, it also tries to constraint the value of minimum weight (`winf`) to be non-zero.

**Error:**

`Error in sample.int(length(toSell), size = 1L) : invalid first argument`

**Code**

```
library(NMOF)
resample <- function(x,...) x[sample.int(length(x),...)]
data <- list(m = colMeans(fundData), ## expected returns
             Sigma = cov(fundData),  ## expected var of returns
             na = dim(fundData)[2L], ## number of assets
             eps = 0.2/100,          ## stepsize for LS
             winf = 0.03,               ## minimum weight
             wsup = 0.5,               ## maximum weight
             lambda = 1)
cat("The Portfolio will consist of at least ", ceiling(1/data$wsup), 
    " assets. \n", sep = "")

OF <- function(w, data){
  data$lambda * (w %*% data$Sigma %*% w) -
    (1 - data$lambda) * sum(w * data$m)
}

neighbour <- function(w, data){
  toSell <- which(w > data$winf)
  toBuy <- which(w < data$wsup)
  i <- toSell[sample.int(length(toSell), size = 1L)]
  j <- toBuy[sample.int(length(toBuy), size = 1L)]
  eps <- runif(1) * data$eps
  eps <- min(w[i] - data$winf, data$wsup - w[j], eps)
  w[i] <- w[i] - eps
  w[j] <- w[j] + eps
  w
}


#Initial Random Solution 
makex<-function(data){
  resample <- function(x,...)
    x[sample.int(length(x),...)]
  w0 <- numeric(data$na)
  nAssets <- resample(ceiling(1/data$wsup):data$na,1L)
  w0[sample(seq_len(data$na),nAssets)] <- runif(nAssets)
  w0/sum(w0)
}
w0 <- makex(data)
algo <- list(x0 = w0, neighbour = neighbour, nS = 5000L)
system.time(sol1 <- LSopt(OF, algo, data))
```

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: It would be good if you showed where in your code the error occurs, is it after `makex(dat)` or ... ?? Can you share an example of `data` so we can see if all variables are there, and the code makes sense? thanks

Comment: @user20650: I have edited my question to show where the error occurs. I guess it occurs while executing the neighbour function, i.e., `neighbour`. I have used the data `fundData` from `NMOF` package. The dataset consists of return values of 200 assets.

Comment: Your `neighbour()` causes the error, i.e., `toSell` or `toBuy` may become `integer(0)`.  If you use `sample()` instead of `sample.int()`, the error doesn't happen (but it doesn't seem to be an essential solution).

Comment: @cuttlefish44: Just for clarification. The R manual says that  `sample.int` is a bare interface in which both `n` and `size` must be supplied as integers. So, is sample with integer values of  `x` and `size` equivalent to `sample.int` ? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html

Comment: I take it that `sample()` with integer and **positive** value of x and size is equivalent to `sample.int` (see `?sample.int`'s Argument `n`). `sample(0L, 1L)` returns `0L` but `sample.int(0L, 1L)` doesn't run. The reason I said "but it doesn't seem to be..." is I can't interpret immediately the results of it is what you want. If `toSell` becomes `integer(0)`, `i <- toSell[sample(length(toSell), size = 1L)]` is `integer(0)`. It means nothing happens with `w[i] <- w[i] - eps`.

Comment: @cuttlefish44: True. Makes sense now. In that case, `sample()` does not help much to solve the problem. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a different neighbourhood function to achieve what you want, or a different way of implementing the constraint.

To see that the neighbourhood is not going to work, set

```
w0 <- numeric(data$na)
w0[1:2] <- 0.5
```

What would be a valid move away from this portfolio? The function will reduce one of the two weights. Then
it will add to any zero weight because they all
satisfy `w < data$wsup`; but it will completely ignore
the `winf` you set. That is not an error in the
function, because it was just never meant for the case
`winf > 0`.

A neighbourhood that enforces a maximum cardinality is
provided in 

[Remarks on 'A comparison of some heuristic optimization methods'](http://enricoschumann.net/R/remarks.htm).

But probably the easiest way to go about this is to make it
a two-step optimisation: in the outer optimisation, you
just select assets that are to be put into the
portfolio. (For an example, see 
[Asset selection with Local Search](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF/vignettes/LSselect.pdf).)
Then, for a given selection of assets, solve your
mean–variance problem.